# ¿Como instalo colorama? Python

Tags: python

Quiero usar colorma, segun yo ya lo instale con :
    sudo pip install colorama
Pero cuando lo intento importar en python me aparece :
[image: El error que me aparece]

Y en la terminal me aparece que ya lo instale :
[image: Terminal]

¿Qué es lo que pasa?
Gracias

Comment: qué versión de Python estás utilizando? y en qué IDE programas?, Muchas veces los IDES crean entornos virtuales (una carpeta llamada venv) por cada nuevo proyecto, los cuales engloban copias del intérprete de Python sin incluir los plugins que has instalado en el intérprete general, como es el caso de Pycharm. Verifica esta información.
Si este es el caso, entonces deberás instalar Colorama dentro del venv haciendo clic en Archivo>Ajustes>Proyecto: nombreDelProyecto> Intérprete y añade con el signo "+" el plugin Colorama.
[![ventana de ajustes del intérprete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccK7D.pn

Answer (score 0):

qué versión de Python estás utilizando? y en qué IDE programas?, Muchas veces los IDES crean entornos virtuales (una carpeta llamada venv) por cada nuevo proyecto, los cuales engloban copias del intérprete de Python sin incluir los plugins que has instalado en el intérprete general, como es el caso de Pycharm. Verifica esta información.
Si este es el caso, entonces deberás instalar Colorama dentro del venv haciendo clic en Archivo>Ajustes>Proyecto: nombreDelProyecto> Intérprete y añade con el signo "+" el plugin Colorama.
[image: ventana de ajustes del intérprete]
En otros IDEs deben existir ajustes parecidos.